# Issues with doclicense, both with fancyhdr and with background

Tags: formatting, header-footer, positioning, fancyhdr

This is an attempt to insert the [doclicense](https://ctan.org/pkg/doclicense) output in each page of a document, using [fancyhdr](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-sa},
    version={3.0}]{doclicense}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{logo}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{ \resizebox{0.4\textwitdh}{!}{\doclicenseThis} }
}

\pagestyle{logo}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\newpage

Some new text.

\end{document}
```

This code doesn't work, generating occurrences of this error

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \newpage
```

at `\newpage`, and several occurrences of this error

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{document}
```

at the end, also simply using `\doclicenseThis` instead of the `resizebox`. Other errors are:

```
Undefined control sequence. \end{document}
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end{document}
\fancyfoot's `E' option without twoside option is useless
```

This is similar to what happens with package [background](https://ctan.org/pkg/background):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-sa},
    version={3.0}
]{doclicense}
\usepackage{background}

\backgroundsetup{contents={\doclicenseThis}}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\newpage

Some new text.

\end{document}
```

which generates several times

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

at `\newpage` and at the end of document.

What could it be the problem and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\doclicenseThis` macro contains a `center` environment, which breaks inside an `\hbox` (`\resizebox` is an `\hbox` with a few more fancies around).

If you try:

```
\resizebox{1cm}{!}{%
\begin{center}
  D'oh
\end{center}
}
```

you'll get the same error.

The issue with `background` is the same. The `contents` of the background are inserted with a Ti*k*Z `\node`, which is another fancy `\hbox`, thus it will fail as well:

```
\tikz\node{%
  \begin{center}
    D'oh
  \end{center}%
};
```

but this one is much trickier to work around, so below I go for the solution using `fancyhdr`.

Besides redefining the `\doclicenseThis`, you can put it in a `minipage` instead of a `\resizebox`. With a few hand-tuning of the sizes you get:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-sa},
    version={3.0}]{doclicense}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{logo}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%
      \def\doclicense@imagewidth{2cm}%
      \tiny
      \doclicenseThis
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{logo}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\newpage

Some new text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is more than enough to use only `fancyhdr`.