# Place object in custom position, but differently for odd and even pages

Tags: formatting, header-footer, positioning, fancyhdr

This is an example page, with a custom footer, containing two different text blocks in the bottom right and bottom left, temporarily using package [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos):

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
  \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
  \setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}

\begin{document}

Beginning of document.

\begin{textblock}{80}(150,260)
Right text
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{80}(12,260)
Left text
\end{textblock}

\newpage

New page of document.

\end{document}
```

The resulting bottom of the page should be:

```
                                  <page number>
                           <some custom empty space>
     Left text                                                      Right text
```

Note that the page number is **above**. This is the first page, an odd page. I would like:

- to swap the positions of "Right text" and "Left text" for the even pages;
- not to create a `textblock` for each page, but define a standard layout to be applied;
- to exclude this layout in some custom pages.

Package [fancyhdr](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) would be ideal for this, but IIUC the page number, the left and right fields are on the same line in the footer. I would like instead to put a custom space between the page number and "Right text" and "Left text".

It doesn't matter which package, between [textpos](https://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) and [fancyhdr](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) (or another one) is used. How to accomplish this?

Comment: With a KOMA class you could create layers. You can certainly do some trickery with fancyhdr and simply "shift" the centered footer. How long will the left/right text be (paragraphs or one-liners)?

Comment: @TeXnician I would keep the number in the default footer, and rather downshift the text. One of the two texts is as in the bottom of the page in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463235/74786), so three short lines and an image; the other one is a one liner, a few words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [fancyhdr](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr), the following workaround is possible:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{logo}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{
  \vspace{1cm}
  Text 1
  }
  \fancyfoot[RE,LO]{
  \vspace{1cm}
  Text 2
  }
}

\pagestyle{logo}

\begin{document}

The following footer will be repeated in each odd page:

\newpage

The following footer will be repeated in each even page:

\newpage

\pagestyle{empty}

The following page has no footer.

\end{document}
```

Adjust `\vspace{1cm}` as desired, but monitoring the log during compilation to avoid the Overfull warning.

[image] [image] [image]